# How to get all data from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to display the student names from db and two buttons for each students.
In my code i am using ajax function.

**controller**

```
    function get_sib_filter()
    {
       $list_id= $this->input->post('id2');
       if(($list_id)==1)
       {
         $filtered_students = $this->home_model->filter_by_sibling(); 
         $new_string = "";
         foreach($filtered_students->result() as $detail)
         {
           $new_string.=$detail->applicant_first_name;
           $new_string=$new_string.'<a href="<?echo base_url();?>home/change_filter_status_green/"'.$detail->applicant_id.'" class="btn green button_style" title="Filter">Selected For Interview</a>';
           $new_string=$new_string.'<a href="<?echo base_url();?>home/change_filter_status_red/"'.$detail->applicant_id.'" class="btn red but_style" title="Rejected">Rejected</a></br>';

        }

      echo $new_string;
     }

   }
```

But i got the last name only(last name and two buttons)

I want list all name and all name having two buttons

Plzz give suggetions..

Comment: Why are you writing `</br>` instead of `<br>`?

Comment: k.than u for ur opinion

Comment: when is `$new_string` defined?

Comment: how is it that youre getting the last name of the student if I dont see youre setting last_name anywhere in your code?

Comment: @Rose That was not an opinion, it was a question. I see `</br>` so often these days, and nobody can tell me why they're doing it!

Comment: @MrLister can you share with us what the difference is between `<br>` and `</br>`? Does it matter?

Comment: This: `'<a href="<?echo base_url();?>home/...` will not work. as youre PHP needs to be concatenated the right way. I would exchange all single quotes with doubles.

Comment: @CodeGodie Yes, it matters. `</br>` is an error. Now if the `br` element was like other elements, it would have a start tag and an end tag, and you could write something like `<br>..</br>`. But never just the end tag `</br>` by itself, that's always an error! Moreover, the `br` element is a void element, meaning that it does not have an end tag. There's only the `<br>`.

Comment: @MrLister Gotcha. But when you say error. When would we encounter this error? Seems like all browsers nowadays dont care which you use.

Comment: @Rose Where should Last Name go?

Comment: @CodeGodie That's because error handling is standardised. Which doesn't imply that errors are therefore OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments above, here are the issues found:

- you never defined `$new_string`
- you are overwriting `$new_string`
- you are not concatenating the `base_url` the right way
- Also, since you are using `base_url` you should be loading the URL helper in your controller (`$this->load->helper('url')`) or autoloading it in `autoload.php`

Try this:

```
$students = $filtered_students->result();
$string = "";
foreach ($students as $student) {
    $string .= $student->applicant_first_name . " ";;
    $string .= "<a href='" . base_url() . "home/change_filter_status_green/$student->applicant_id' class='btn green button_style' title='Filter'>Selected For Interview</a> | ";
    $string .= "<a href='" . base_url() . "home/change_filter_status_red/$student->applicant_id'' class='btn red but_style' title='Rejected'>Rejected</a><br/>";
}
echo $string;
```

Comment: Name is not displayed? How do you have it saved in your database?

Comment: to not group the links ,place a space and a separator `|` after the first `a`  I included that in my answer.

Comment: I understand, but I need to know your database table structure. Can you provide that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91109/discussion-between-codegodie-and-rose).

Comment: Can you post your model method in your original question?

Comment: Yup I see it.remove the `order_by` line in your model method and see if you still have the same problem.

Comment: @Rose I would really like to help you figure this out. Would you want to do a Teamviewer session?

Comment: Are you familiar with Teamviewer? I can help you remotely so that we can troubleshoot your code together. There are a lot of other causes for your problem such as database structure.

Comment: THank u so much..I got it some design issues in the button otherwise ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the string here. Please make some changes as shown below.

```
$new_string = ""; // Define $new_string..
foreach($filtered_students->result() as $detail){
   $new_string.=$detail->applicant_first_name;
   $new_string.='<a href="'.base_url().'home/change_filter_status_green/"'.$detail->applicant_id.'" class="btn green button_style" title="Filter">Selected For Interview</a>';
   $new_string.='<a href="'.base_url().'home/change_filter_status_red/"'.$detail->applicant_id.'" class="btn red but_style" title="Rejected">Rejected</a><br />';
}
```

And also make sure what are you getting from this variable: `$filtered_students`.
You can check it by `print_r($filtered_students);`

Comment: try this..now shows all names and buttons..but button links are not working that shows some error page

Comment: This: `'<a href="<?echo base_url();?>home/...` will not work. as youre PHP needs to be concatenated the right way. I would exchange all single quotes with doubles.

Comment: When i click the button it shows" Disallowed key Character"

Comment: Nothing is listed now

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
      function get_sib_filter()
{
   $list_id= $this->input->post('id2');
   if($list_id == 1)
   {
     $filtered_students = $this->home_model->filter_by_sibling(); 
     $new_string = "";
     $count = 0;
     foreach($filtered_students->result() as $detail)
     {
        if($count == 0){
            $new_string = "<a href='".base_url('home/change_filter_status_green/').$detail->applicant_id."' class='btn green button_style' title='Filter'>Selected For Interview</a><a href='".base_url('home/change_filter_status_red').$detail->applicant_id."' class='btn red but_style title='Rejected'>Rejected</a>";
            $count++;
        }else{
            $new_string .= $new_string."<a href='".base_url('home/change_filter_status_green/').$detail->applicant_id."' class='btn green button_style' title='Filter'>Selected For Interview</a><a href='".base_url('home/change_filter_status_red').$detail->applicant_id."' class='btn red but_style title='Rejected'>Rejected</a>";
        }

     }

  echo $new_string;
 }
```

}

Answer (score -2):

change your model like this:

```
function filter_by_sibling()
   {
        $this->db->select('applicant_id,applicant_first_name');
        $this->db->from('student_application');
        $this->db->order_by('sib_count','desc');
        $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        return $result; 
   }
```

Modify your controller function like this:

```
function get_sib_filter()
    {
       $list_id= $this->input->post('id2');
       if(($list_id)==1)
       {
         $filtered_students = $this->home_model->filter_by_sibling(); 
         $new_string = "";
         foreach($filtered_students as $detail)
         {
           $new_string .=$detail['applicant_first_name'];
           $new_string .='<a href="'.base_url().'home/change_filter_status_green/'.$detail['applicant_id'].'" class="btn green button_style" title="Filter">Selected For Interview</a>';
           $new_string .='<a href="'.base_url().'home/change_filter_status_red/'.$detail['applicant_id'].'" class="btn red but_style" title="Rejected">Rejected</a><br />';
        }

      echo $new_string;
     }

   }
```